# Manifest Merger Error on Android Studio

Tags: android

I'm basically trying to move from one activity to a google maps activity.
I added the MapsActivity File onto the manifest file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="mahboob.cmec">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".menu" />
        <activity android:name=".Reference" />
        <activity android:name=".Registration" />
        <activity android:name=".RegistrationComplete" />
        <activity android:name=".electricitybill" />
        <activity android:name=".GasBill" />
        <activity android:name=".BillReport" />
        <activity android:name=".SetTarget" />
        <activity android:name=".EcoReport" />
        <activity android:name=".MapsActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".ManageContract" />
        <activity android:name=".GraphReport" />

        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

When I run the code, I get the following output:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
>   > Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

I'm not sure what the problem is, I assumed that I need to add the MapsActivity class to my Manifest file which I have done.

```
OUTPUT:
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:assembleDebug]
:app:clean
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2340Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72340Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMediarouterV72200Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42340Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2340Library
:app:prepareComBasgeekballAwesomeValidation13Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices750Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds750Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics750Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppindexing750Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppinvite750Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppstate750Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase750Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCast750Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesDrive750Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesFitness750Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGames750Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm750Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIdentity750Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation750Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps750Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesNearby750Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPanorama750Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus750Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesSafetynet750Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWallet750Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWearable750Library
:app:prepareComMcxiaokeVolleyLibraryAar100Library
:app:prepareComNumetriclabzNumandroidchartsNumandroidcharts103Library
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl
:app:compileDebugRenderscript
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig
:app:mergeDebugShaders
:app:compileDebugShaders
:app:generateDebugAssets
:app:mergeDebugAssets
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources
:app:processDebugManifest
C:\Users\User\Pictures\work\CMEC26\CMEC16\CMEC14\CMEC\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:52:9-54:68 Error:
    Element activity#mahboob.cmec.MapsActivity at AndroidManifest.xml:52:9-54:68 duplicated with element declared at AndroidManifest.xml:36:9-50
C:\Users\User\Pictures\work\CMEC26\CMEC16\CMEC14\CMEC\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml Error:
    Validation failed, exiting
See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.
:app:processDebugManifest FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 54.528 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Comment: Could you post the logs? You can find them in the Android Monitor tab in the bottom of Android Studio.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you can try clean project and then build. If the problem is not resolved, you can try second option.

Secondly, This is a general error for Android development. If you can not find the error, you have to look Gradle console informations. But default gradle console informations is close. You need to open it.

1. File->Settings
2. Build,Execution,Deployment -> Compiler
3. `--stacktrace --debug` -> write to command-line options
4. OK

And then you can look gradle console. You will see more informations. You can detect error here.

Comment: Use `--stacktrace --debug --scan` to get full insights.

Comment: Yes, scan command can use but it can produce some garbage verbose so might be difficult to read

Answer (score 0):

You have two `MapsActivity` in the manifest. Delete one of them.